# Question on Cassy (when to use it and what type of backups it takes) - backup tool for Cassandra

Tags: cassy

I have just started on `Cassy`, the backup take snapshots of `Cassandra`.

Referring to the documentation(https://github.com/scalar-labs/cassy)

Question 1) Can I store back up of the the blob in local laptop filesystem? I don't have an `S3` account. While I can create it, I'll like to have a backup on my local system as well? Would I be able to restore data as well from my local machine?

Question 2 ) `Cassy` doesn't take backup of `commitlogs`. What is the implication of this? Is it that if a transaction is in `commitlog` but not on disk then that transaction would not be backed up? If I don't want this, should should I stop my application and then do back up? I am thinking that if I end up stopping the application then I can just use the standard C* tools for backup as there won't be any transactions going on. Isn't it?

Question 3) I can't select keyspaces to take/restore backups. Does this mean that I backup entire directories and not specific databases?
Operate easily with GUI

Answer (score 0):

Question 1) We are working on supporting copying files to a server via SSH. (The server can be local)

Question 2) Since we don't support point-in-time restore, we don't backup commit logs. A restored node will get the necessary information from other replicas to catch up to the latest data when repaired. Of course, if the quorum of replicas loses data, some transactions will be lost. You can use the cluster-wide backup to mitigate the problem.

Question 3) You can select keyspaces with `--keyspaces` option.